# No block are producing while running node in dev mode

Tags: substrate-node-template, block-production

Even though I set genesis staker [here](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/8405ddf83687c587b9cfac799f0b536a7580c073/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L230) no block are producing. Someone please help me.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate % ./target/release/node-template --dev
2023-07-02 08:15:58 Substrate Node    
2023-07-02 08:15:58 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-98d3cb5bfe8    
2023-07-02 08:15:58 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2023    
2023-07-02 08:15:58  Chain specification: Development    
2023-07-02 08:15:58   Node name: tearful-feast-1220    
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate % ./target/release/node-template --dev
2023-07-02 08:18:07 Substrate Node    
2023-07-02 08:18:07 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-98d3cb5bfe8    
2023-07-02 08:18:07 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2023    
2023-07-02 08:18:07  Chain specification: Development    
2023-07-02 08:18:07   Node name: nosy-creator-5275    
2023-07-02 08:18:07  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-07-02 08:18:07  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/substrated8RqHa/chains/dev/db/full    
2023-07-02 08:18:07 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
2023-07-02 08:18:07 [0]  generated 0 npos voters, 0 from validators and 0 nominators    
2023-07-02 08:18:07 [0]  generated 0 npos targets    
2023-07-02 08:18:08  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x5974…be17, header-hash: 0x35c3…43f4)    
2023-07-02 08:18:08  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2023-07-02 08:18:10 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs    
2023-07-02 08:18:10   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWEk1L8JKCSJHhZyrypSLpbPnnhNq4qi7XxKmeZCHP3wR1    
2023-07-02 08:18:10  Operating system: macos    
2023-07-02 08:18:10  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2023-07-02 08:18:10  Highest known block at #0    
2023-07-02 08:18:10 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2023-07-02 08:18:10 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=["*"]    
2023-07-02 08:18:10 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]    
2023-07-02 08:18:15  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x35c3…43f4), finalized #0 (0x35c3…43f4), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-07-02 08:18:20  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x35c3…43f4), finalized #0 (0x35c3…43f4), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see from repo you provided, you are changing consensus from `AURA` to `BABE` but as I go through your [runtime](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/8405ddf83687c587b9cfac799f0b536a7580c073/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1243-L1251), there were still the implementation of `AURA` consensus present, that needs to be removed and also you haven't changed the [service.rs](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/8405ddf83687c587b9cfac799f0b536a7580c073/node/src/service.rs) file, the file is still using `AURA` and not `BABE`, as most of the spawn tasks are handled there you need to do changes there also. Refer [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs) for changes in `service.rs` file.